# Warning unable to restore previous frame and giving error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tbxml, yahoo-weather-api

My iPhone app crashes and gives the following warning

```
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
```

Here is code where actauly it crashes

```
+(id) tbxmlWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL;{
    return [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:aURL];
}


-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL{
    return [self initWithURL:aURL];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `-initWithURL:` method is calling itself recursively. Each time it does that, it adds a stack frame, and eventually you run out of stack space and crash. The debugger typically doesn't give you much useful information when that happens.

Did you mean this?

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL{
    return [super initWithURL:aURL];
}
```

Comment: Ya exactly. It sorted my problem